# Simple clutter-free way to call multiple variables

Tags: objective-c, variables, call, clutter

I'm looking to do something like

```
int ItemNames;
typedef enum ItemNames {apple, club, vial} ItemNames;    
+(BOOL)GetInventoryItems{return ItemNames;}
apple=1; //Compiler Error.
```

The issue is, is that I cannot set a variable in an enum to a new value. The compiler tells me that I have "redeclared" an integer in the enum. Also, it won't correctly return the values.
So instead I have to use an if statement for each item to check if it exists like so.

```
+ (void)GetInventoryItems
{
    if (apple <= 1){NSLog(@"Player has apple");}
    if (club <= 1){ NSLog(@"Player has club");}
    if (vial <= 1){NSLog(@"Player has vial");}
    if (apple == 0 && club == 0 && vial == 0){NSLog(@"Player's Inventory is Empty.");}
}
```

Is there a work around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to use the wrong data structure. An enum is just a list of possible values, a data type and not a variable.

```
typedef struct {
  int apple : 1;
  int club : 1;
  int vial : 1;
}
inventory_type;

inventory_type room;

room.apple = 1;

if (room.apple) NSLog (@"There's an apple");
if (room.club) NSLg (@"There's a club!");
```

The colon and number after each element of the typedef tells the compiler how many bits to use, so in this case a single bit (i.e., a binary value) is available.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure what room is (neither does the compiler), but struct was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I didn't know what you were creating an inventory of so I said it was a room; it's just a variable name.

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more specific than that. What errors?

Answer (score 1):

The enum values are constants, so they can't be modified. Objective-c is a c-based language, so ItemNames isn't an object, it is a type.

Comment: Of my book "Learning Objective-C 2.0" It tells me that enum values are not constants and it says that "apple=1;" will work as a redefinition. However, this not working how would you do the exact same thing without enums?

Answer (score 1):

I find it hard to wrap my head around your question. Are you sure you know how `enum` works in C? It’s just a way to conveniently declare numeric constants. For example:

```
enum { Foo, Bar, Baz };
```

Is something like:

```
static const NSUInteger Foo = 0;
static const NSUInteger Bar = 1;
static const NSUInteger Baz = 2;
```

If you want to pack several inventory items into a single value, you might use a bit string:

```
enum {
    Apple  = 1 << 1,
    Banana = 1 << 2,
    Orange = 1 << 3
};

NSUInteger inventory = 0;

BOOL hasApple  = (inventory & Apple);
BOOL hasBanana = (inventory & Banana);

inventory = inventory | Apple; // adds an Apple into the inventory
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, This is a good alternate way. However, to avoid myself confusion involving bitwise shifts and the need to redefine a variable to anything and anywhere in the program, I'm going to use struct. :-)

Comment: Yes, the struct approach is better, I didn’t know you can pack the struct like that.